# macOS 14.1.2 firewall blocking Colima from running

Tags: firewall, sonoma, docker

I have macOS 14.1.2 with the Firewall turned on, but not set to block all

```
Firewall is enabled. (State = 1)
Block all DISABLED!
Automatically allow signed built-in software ENABLED
Automatically allow downloaded signed software ENABLED
Stealth mode disabled
```

When I exec Colima start, it will not start because the firewall is blocking it from connecting to the local VM.

It works when I turn the firewall off, but as soon as I turn it back on, it stops working again.

How do I modify the firewall policy to allow
`/opt/homebrew/bin/colima` to connect to any port, as well as Docker from `/opt/homebrew/bin/docker`?